# Accidental changes in BuildConfig.java, unable to restore

Tags: android, gradle

Even after editing, the moment i build gradle it is restored. 
[buildConfig.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUhrw.png)
[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH8tE.png)

Comment: could you please share your build.gradle file? i think the issue is in there where you are declaring this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BuildConfig.java is generated by Android build tools. Any modification to the file will be gone when configuration is done.

Btw, It looks like you have a `UNIQUE_FIREBASE_ROOT_URL` property under `buildTypes.debug`;

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "UNIQUE_FIREBASE_ROOT_URL", "https://~~~~"
    }
}
```

The url part should be written like this:
`'"http://~~~~"'`
(surround it by single quotation marks again)

Comment: Yes i understand that, that's what i wanna know. How can i change it?

Comment: That's what I thought. Look at your build.gradle file. And change the URL string as I explained in this answer. (Add single quotation marks)

Comment: Thank a lot. Sorry for being so dumb. :')

Answer (score 0):

It quite clearly says above it - "Files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited".

If you need to change something you need to change it in a different file.

Comment: Yes i understand that, that's what i wanna know. How can i change it?

Comment: That depends on what you want to change?

Comment: I want put the link in quotes.

Comment: https://androidwithdivya.wordpress.com/2016/02/10/how-to-connect-your-android-app-to-firebase-as-backend-solution/ - see step 6. This should be set in grade.properties or build.gradle

Comment: My buildConfig.java is loading value from disk.

Comment: It's not loaded from disk, it is automatically generated from the values you set in your build.gradle and other files. Change the correct files, sync your project and you will see the values in buildConfig.java change. See @nexus5x answer - this is an excerpt from build.gradle.